# MySQL get result columns based on row data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. The first one contains fruits:

```
+----+--------+
| id | fruit  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | banana |
+----+--------+
| 2  | orange |
+----+--------+
```

The second one contains the amount of fruits each basket has:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| id | basket | fruit_id | amount |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| 1  | a      | 1        | 5      |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| 2  | a      | 2        | 10     |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| 3  | b      | 1        | 8      |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| 4  | b      | 2        | 12     |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
```

Now I want to get something like this.

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| fruit_id | basket_a | basket_b |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | 5        | 8        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 2        | 10       | 12       |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Obviously it has to work on `n` number of baskets. I would be more than happy to share any progress/piece of code, but unfortunately I don't know how to start off. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Search for: rows to columns/PIVOT. Do you know all basktets in advance or do you need it dynamic?

Comment: @lad2025 I need it dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having n numbers of columns is not a good idea. Do you really want your result in table format?

Comment: Well, I have to be able to create a `html` table using`php`.

Comment: Okay! Then you can have first <th> as fruit id then make loop for basket names as rest of <th> of table you want to create.

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT(basket) FROM fruit_details ORDER BY basket"                                You can use this query to get basket names.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.fruit_id,case when b.basket = 'a' then b.amount end as 'basket_a',
case when b.basket = 'b' then b.amount end as 'basket_b' from table 1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id group by fruit_id;
```

please check above query,is this what you want ?

Comment: What if I have  dozens of baskets?

Comment: then you must be requires columns for all baskets right ??

Comment: Yes, but I want them to be generated dynamically without declaring all of them in the query.

Comment: but you have to declare it in query, how would you come to know which basket it returns the result for ??

Comment: in your result query, You have mentioned amount of basket_a should come in column2, how would you get the dynamic result without declaring it ??
Are you clear on what you want to do ??
if yes, Can you explain in detail in the question itself with tabular form ??