# PHP & mysql display data from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table which contain have data like as mentioned below:

```
Table1

TID     Name
 1      Salman 
 2      ABC 
 3      XYZ
```

Table2

```
SID     STID   SUBJECT
 1       1      English
 2       1      Math
 3       2      Physics
 4       2      Math
```

Table1 TID foreign key in Table2 STID. I want to collect data from two table and display in PHP as mentioned below:

```
Name        Subject1    Subject2
Salman      English     Math
ABC         Physic      Math
```

Comment: Same column name not valid in table2 `TTID`

Comment: i have updated the question.

Comment: ok, You will get in same column with user subject but you can not get it like subject1, subject2 and so on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027062/mysql-get-result-columns-based-on-row-data/37029435#37029435 this link may help you.

Comment: @SalmanKarim can you explain subject1 and subject2 concept ??

Comment: This is example only. I have something else which is exactly what's my requirement?

Comment: What if there are more than 2 subjects per STID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is my suggestion algorithm

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("HOST", "USER NAME", "USER PASS", "YOUR DATABASE");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table1");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$TID = $row['TID'];
$Name = $row['Name'];
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table2 where `TTID` = $TID");
echo "$Name \t";
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
$SUBJECT = $row2['SUBJECT'];
echo "$SUBJECT \t";
}
echo '<br/>';
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: You can change structure of code according to your requirments

Comment: Also i changed first TTID to T2ID in you first sample

Comment: I am trying your suggestion and let u know very soon

Comment: @SalmanKarim Please feel free to contact with me if you need to further information

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number of subjects that can be assigned to a student,

Please check this query

```
SELECT A.Name  , 
(SELECT subject from Table2 where STID = A.TID limit 0,1 ) as SUBJECT1,
(SELECT subject from Table2 where STID = A.TID limit 1,1 ) as SUBJECT2
FROM  Table1 A
```